# Quicklaunch not getting updated for the first time in sharepoint in application page

Tags: quick-launch

after updating quick launch nodes,in the first time load of the pagwe , quicklaunch items are not getting updated,utill and unless we refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a publishing site, the behavior could be caused by a misconfigured cache user. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx) for details